# Implement FIFO data structure in javascript, Without array pop, push, shift methods?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I came across an interesting problem where the challenge was to Implement FIFO, without making use of Array pop, push, shift etc.

I searched many answers but they either implement custom pop, push and iterator methods(map, filter etc) but none implement shift/ unshift.

Help me out here.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: So, you just want to re-implement array methods in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you asking for how to implement a FIFO data structure without using arrays or just without using those array methods?

Comment: Without Array what other option we do have to store & maintain the data ?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of this exercise for you to figure out how to do it on your own, not search for code on the Internet? Programming is not copy/paste, it's a creative process.

Comment: `shift` and `unshift` copy each array element to the adjacent element (going down for `shift`, going up for `unshift`). It's just a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a kind of practical question, since JavaScript doesn't come with an efficient queue.  Usually, you just use `push` to add and `shift` to remove, but `shift` takes O(N) time, so this is very costly when the queue gets long.

The solution I use requires only one extra variable (`start`) and reduces the cost to remove an item from O(N) to amortized O(1).  Items would still be added with `array.push(item)`, but since you can't use that I'll just use `array[array.length]=item`, which does exactly the same thing.

I'm not going to wrap this in a class, since in real life it's rarely appropriate:

```js
let start=0;
let array=[];

function addLast(item) {
  array[array.length] = item;
}

function removeFirst() {
  if (start >= array.length) {
    return undefined;
  }
  const result = array[start++];
  if (start >= array.length - start) {
      //move all the elements into the free space at beginning
      let d=0;
      for (let i=start; i<array.length; ++i) {
        array[d++] = array[i];
      }
      start=0;
      array.length = d;
  }
  return result;
}

addLast(1);
addLast(2);
addLast(3);
console.log(removeFirst());
addLast(4);
console.log(removeFirst());
console.log(removeFirst());
addLast(5);
console.log(removeFirst());
console.log(removeFirst());
```

The procedure is very simple.  Instead of shifting all the elements every time we remove one, as shift would do, we wait until we've removed at least as many elements as we have to shift.  That ensures that, on average, there's at most one element shifted for each one removed.